# Does LKM resides in Heap?

Tags: linux, kernel, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I know that the kernel load the Loadable Kernel Modules (LKM) using `vmalloc()`

Is it safe to assume that entire LKMs are residing in heap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More precise, memory for kernel module is allocated using `vmalloc_exec()`.

> Is it safe to assume that entire LKMs are residing in heap?

It depends on what you expect from *residing in heap*. You may assume that none of kernel module element is residing inside kernel core.